# Success function is not getting invoked in ajax GET method

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-ajax

In this code I am facing a problem in the `success` function. I tried a lot but it is going to the `error` function. The `#action-button` calls the JavaScript Method.

```
<button id="action-button">Click me to load info!</button>
<div id="info"></div>
<small>
    Demo created by <a href="https://twitter.com">Twitter</a>
</small>
```

```js
$('#action-button').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'sampleurl',
        data: { format: 'json' },
        error: function() {
            $('#info').html('<p>An error has occurred</p>');
        },
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function(data) {
            $('#info').html('<p>Successd</p>');
        },
        type: 'GET'
    });
});
```

Comment: The error handler is hit if the request returns anything other than `200 OK`, if this is the case it's most likely an issue server-side. Try debugging there first, and checking the console to see what the returned error is.

Comment: Probably being blocked by the browser's XSS protection.

Comment: I have tried compiling the url in POSTMAN, there i am getting the exact data & in that i am getting 200 ok.but it is not coming in the javascript coding

Comment: That URL does not give an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header in its response. The AJAX request is almost certainly being blocked by your browser. The console will give you more information. Read [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) for more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I have mentioned in the comments above, the AJAX query is being blocked because of [XSS protection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS).

Running your provided jsFiddle in IE (and placing a breakpoint in the `error()` callback) gives the error:

> Access is denied

And running it in Firefox gives the following error:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://0daf70fe0a6244fe... This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.

You will have to add an appropriate `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header to the API call at http://sampleURL.

Answer (score 2):

If you're sending json to the server try adding conetentType: application/json

Also are you expecting the response to be of jsonp content type ? mismatch in this can also be the issue.

Comment: I have tried with that also, If i am giving another this url  :http://api.joind.in/v2.1/talks/10889 data are getting parsed.

Comment: Your example url returns text/html not json. Did you try changing the dataType to json ?

Comment: Ok, i've added crossDomain: true to your ajax call on fiddle. I get an "unexpected token" error in the response. make sure the response is in the correct format

Answer (score 0):

If any problem happen during ajax call, such as, wrong url or error on server, `success` function will not be fired. And if every thing is ok, HTTP status will be `200 OK` and therefore success event will be fired. Also, you have `dataType: 'jsonp'` in your options that does not match with post data. This can be one possible problem.  You can check the error in the Firebug and post it for better help.